# Hide UISearchController when segue to another view

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uisearchcontroller

I'd like to hide my search bar from the tableHeaderView when I segue. How can I do this? I create the search bar as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   resultSearchController = ({
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)       //  The results of the search will be presented in the current Table View, so the searchResultsController parameter of the UISearchController init method is set to nil.

        searchController.delegate = self        
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self          // Without this selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange won't get called.
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true    // NOTE: if false and tapping on a reminder to go the its details and then back then the titles may be screwed up.
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false       // NOTE: If true it would result in the filtered list not being scrollable.
        searchController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.definesPresentationContext = false    

        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = SCOPEBAR_OPTIONS.descriptionArray
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        return searchController
    })()
```

I tried to simply set it to nil like this, but no luck:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dismiss searchcontroller use below method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
  searchController.active = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what **was worked** for me (Swift 4):

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         print("prepare for segue")
         searchController.isActive = false
    }
```

Method `definesPresentationContext` in `viewDidLoad()` **didn't work** for me neither:

```
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

nor:

```
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

nor:

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewDidLoad()` you can add the next line for that purpose

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```